# How to extract error data from Apollo resolver?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

I have an apollo server with a resolver like this:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {         
    return service.searchForUsers(searchQuery)           
        .then(...doSomething)           
            .catch(error => {             
                reject({ errorCode: error.code });           
         });       
    });
});
```

I have a graphql query in my client like this:

```
query userSearch($searchQuery: String!) {
   searchUsers(searchQuery: $searchQuery) {
     ...usersFragment   }
}
```

When I catch the resolver from my client, it looks like this, where my intended error object gets wrapped inside error.message in a malformed JSON.

```
error = {
    extraInfo: undefined,
    message: "{\"name\":\"Error\",\"message\":\"Unexpected error value: { errorCode: 102 }\",\"stack\":[]}",
    networkError: ...,
    stack: ...
  }
```

Now I know that this is the format of an Apollo Error, but I don't want to manually parse this object to get the expected error data. This is hard to parse because the .message is not a valid JSON string, there is whitespace in between the characters.

Is there any other way I can reject the error in my resolver, or any other way I can shape my graphql query in the client to fix this error jargon?

I've tried adding some fields to my graphql query like this, but the error field does not seem to be exposed.

```
query userSearch($searchQuery: String!) {
    searchUsers(searchQuery: $searchQuery) {
      ...usersFragment
       }
    error {
      message
    }
  }
```

Comment: Why would you wrap a new Promise around something that's _already_ a promise?

Comment: Theres a lot of other logic in the actual code that I removed for the sake of keeping the question simple. When copy pasting over i deleted that important logic but kept the wrapping promise so it looks weird here